# AI to PDF, mask over photo doesn't show

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, gradient, mask

I layered a gradient over a photo and masked it to create a fade. When I save the file as a PDF and place the file in an email the image doesn't show the fade. I've saved it every way I can think of as a high quality print, press quality, et. I've played around with the compatibility, checked and unchecked the options available. No change, the fade still, well, fades. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clipping mask over photo doesn't show in PDF](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122842/clipping-mask-over-photo-doesnt-show-in-pdf)

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times. Is's best to refer back to your *original* question and edit it if necessary. Be aware, browser and email client abilities to display a complex PDF accurately vary considerably.

Comment: Sorry, I thought this was a different problem because it was in a different file and I was using different tools. I'll try to keep this in mind next time I'm posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem. I saved an AI file, which had a layering mask of a gradient over a photo, as a PDF to print. When I open the PDF with Acrobat Reader it opens okay, with the layering mask. But when I open the PDF with Chrome or Firefox, it doesn't show the gradient.

I couldn't find the problem within the PDF settings. The way I found to surpass this was to flatten the image with the clipping mask (not the best solution, but now the gradient appears the way it should no matter where I open the PDF file).